# iOS 7 Developing for 3.5 and 4 inch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7, retina-display

Hi i am developing an application for iOS 7 actually the application runs in a 3.5 display and my plan is to upload it to the app store.
I´m not using auto layout so it doesn´t fit into a 4 inch display. With this specifications can I upload it to the app store or is mandatory to develop the app for an 4 inch display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must support the 4" display.

> Starting May 1 (2013), new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5.

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get passed Apple Submission Program, your UI will have to look consistent across device screens. So yes. Think about your users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to support both iPhone screen sizes. It is possible to make two interfaces and differentiate between them using the following precompiler macro

`#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )`

This is a boolean, and you can use it in any other code you have in your app, like if you were to change the interface based on which screen size, call it in a if statement in your ApplicationDelegate method

`if (IS_WIDESCREEN) // load 4" nib`